# How to make javascript prompt form required

Tags: javascript, html

I made a password verification field in js, but it doesn't work correctly and you can just skip it, and it will say that you entered correct password:

```
function checkPasOne(password) {

let enteredpas = prompt('Enter password:', '')

if (enteredpas == 673577) { alert('Correct')

    

} else {

    alert('Wrong password')

    return checkPasOne()

}

}

checkPasOne()
```

I tried to make it using html but it doesn't work and I need to do it in js. I expected it will don't let you pass until you enter right password, but it let you pass only if you press cancel and it says you wrong password even if you write correct password.

And can I just remove cancel button and make correct password work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point #1:
it will let me pass if I give the correct password. Otherwise, it will not let me pass. Therefore I can use a simple condition.

```
if (enteredpas == 673577) {
      alert("Correct");
      return;
    } else {
      alert("Wrong password");
      checkPasOne();
    }
  }
```

Point #2: If I press cancel, it will let me pass by showing me the wrong password. To do this, we need an extra layer of condition. It will check whether `enteredpas` contains any value or not. Because by pressing the cancel button it will return a `null` value.

So the final code will be:

```js
function checkPasOne(password) {
  let enteredpas = prompt("Enter password:", "");

  console.log(enteredpas);

  if (enteredpas) {
    if (enteredpas == 673577) {
      alert("Correct");
      return;
    } else {
      alert("Wrong password");
      checkPasOne();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Wrong password");
    return;
  }
}
checkPasOne();
```

*As far as I know, you can't remove the cancel button in the prompt.*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the cancel from `prompt()` in JS. I ran the code and it seemed to run just fine. What do you mean just skip it? When I pressed cancel, it said wrong password and went back into the loop.

Comment: When I tested it on mobile, on Chrome, Opera and Eruda,  when I pressed the cancel button on that prompt it said that password is correct. When I tested in on Chrome on my PC result was same